# How to make FastAPI's path operation function to commit on successful return

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm developing web API server with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy 1.4

What I'm going to do is like

1. Commit on the end of all path operation function **implicitly** if there is no error occured.
2. When HTTPException is occured, rollback the transaction.

In short, **how to make FastAPI's path operation function atomic** like database transaction.

These code snippets are what I'm using from tiangolo's full-stack-fastapi-postgresql project (https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

app = FastAPI()

@app.put("/users/{id}")
def update_user(
    id: int,
    new_name: str,
    new_login_id: str,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
):
    """
    Simple User update API
    """
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.id == id).first()

    if not user:
        raise HTTPExecption(404, "User not found")

    user.name = new_name
    
    if db.query(User).filter(User.login_id == new_login_id).first():
        # if login id is already exist, I want to rollback update name
        raise HTTPExecption(409, "Already used login id")

    user.login_id = new_login_id

    db.add(user)
    # db.commit()
    # I don't want to write db.commit() at the end of every path operation func. 

    return
```

I've tried in several ways

First, using FastAPI (Starlette) Middleware

I can't find way to pass db (Session) to middleware

Second, Add db.commit() at get_db()'s finally block

db.commit() is called even HTTPException is raised.

So I tried to use FastAPI Error handler for calling db.rollback() when HTTPExecption is raised, but I can't find a way to pass db (Session) to error handler.

How can I acheive it?

Comment: Try putting `db.commit()` after the `yield` statement in `get_db`, but not in the finally block (the whole point of the finally block is that it runs even if there is no exception).

Comment: @M.O. `db.commit()` is called even HTTPExecption is raised. I should add `db.rollback()` at HTTPException handler.

Comment: Be careful with commit after yield and `autoflush=False`, response is sent before the commit is done, in that case, operation might not be committed but response to client is 200: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/869#issuecomment-585940169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, i think SQLAlchemy won't commit data if there is some exception occured in a transaction.

Then, if you want to pass `db`, you can

```py
def get_db(request) -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        request.state.db = db
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

1. About exception handler, `finally` code block will be exceuted before exception handler,so you can't rollback in exception handler.
2. About middleware, all http path operation exceptions were catched in `starlette.ExceptionMiddleware` which is fixed in FastAPI app. So if you want to custom it you should create a middleware `CustomExceptionMiddleware` , you can use `db` in it:

   ```py
   class CustomExceptionMiddleware(starlette.Exception):
           async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:
               if scope["type"] != "http":
                   await self.app(scope, receive, send)
                   return

               response_started = False

               async def sender(message: Message) -> None:
                   nonlocal response_started

                   if message["type"] == "http.response.start":
                       response_started = True
                   await send(message)

               try:
                   await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
                   a = 0
               except Exception as exc:
                   # some operation
                   request = Request(scope, receive=receive)
                   # request.state.db is usable
                   # some operation
   ```

   then you must rewrite `FastAPI.build_middleware_stack()` to replace `ExceptionMiddleware` by `CustomExceptionMiddleware`. Now you can execute `rollback` or other operation in `CustomExceptionMiddleware`. Also you shoud remove `db.close()` from `get_db()` to `CustomExceptionMiddleware`.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue OP is asking about; The db is made available through FastAPIs dependency system, no need to attach it as a request's state (since this wouldn't be invoked unless it was declared as a Dependency regardless, it's usually way clearer to just use a `Depends` in your view controller definition.

Comment: @MatsLindh yeah. i modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

```py
sql_engine = ...
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(sql_engine, autoflush=False, autocommit=False)

async def get_session(request: Request) -> Generator:
    try:
        logger.debug("Creating database session.")
        database_session = SessionLocal()
        yield database_session
        database_session.commit()
    finally:
        logger.debug("Closing database session.")
        database_session.close()
```

But THEN **do not forget** to flush at the end of your method so the changes are evaluated and the commit is safe:

```py
@router.post(path="/somewhere")
async def create_database(
    your_data: dict = Body()
    session: Session = Depends(database.get_session),
) -> None:
    ...
    logger.debug("Flush changes to database.")
    session.flush()
```

If data are incorrect or there is BD conflict, flush will fail and your exception handlers will catch the exception before sending the response.

I was looking for a way to raise also an error if `commit` is called without manual `flush`, however did not find it (I suppose the best is to rely on testing). Open to suggestions.